# статус код BadRequest 200

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

в апи контроллере возвращаю

```
return BadRequest("Данный клиент уже является подтвержденным клиентом и не может быть добавлен");
```

но далее в

```
public class LogAdminEventActionFilter : IActionFilter {
//...
public async void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode != 200)
                return;
```

приходит 200 код и программа продолжает работу, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то StatusCode у HttpResponse устанавливается после того, как будет выполнен результат (экземпляр IActionResult, который вернулся из метода контроллера). Попробуйте переопределить метод OnResultExecuted и сделать ту же проверку в нем. Результат тот же или как-то помнялся?

Comment: да, я решил вопрос, так и надо делать